# Скроллинг в iframe по кнопке JS

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe

интересует такой вопрос. 
Есть iframe, встроен на страницу WordPress, скроллинг реализовал функцией JS, т.е. на самой странице (html где сам код располагается) все окей, работает скроллинг вверх при клике на кнопку input, но в самом iframe эта возможность пропадает

Подскажите кто-нибудь, как сделать так, чтобы при клике на кнопку страница поднималась вверх в самом iframe?

Comment: Вы не можете управлять содержимым iframe. Никак.

Comment: @KAGGDesign это ложь.

Comment: @Diskyp чтобы комментировать, хорошо бы ещё выучить русский язык. Ложь - это преднамеренное искажение фактов. В данном случае - мой комментарий - это, как максимум, ошибочное суждение, но не ложь. А на самом деле - это правильное суждение, из которого есть только одно исключение (iframe на том же домене). Но по практике почти никто не использует iframe на собственном домене. Так что вероятность того, что мой комментарий правильный в данном конкретном случае - процентов 90.

Comment: @KAGGDesign окей, тогда скажу так: ваш комментарий при переводе в булево будет равен false. Тем более ваш комментарий не содержал ссылок на этот субъективный случай (из которого в любом случае не понятен адрес iframe) а создавал, какбы, объективное общее утверждение. Так что и некоторые операнды из второго вашего комментария можно привести к false.

Comment: Diskyp, KAGG Design, ребята не ругайтесь) Так можно или нет? Да, iframe располагается на другом домене, но его можно и перенести на этот же домен если будет работать, вопрос только как его заставить работать? Переход вверх при клике на кнопку input (там мультишаговый калькулятор)

Comment: @BloodKnight чуть ниже располагается мой ответ. Для iframe контента со своего домена он рабочий, я тестировал. Если нужна доп. инфа, спрашивайте в комментариях к ответу.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете управлять `iframe`ом как обычно, получив его содержимое jquery методом `.contents()` (на чистом js тоже можно, но выглядит не так красиво)

```
$('iframe').contents().find('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},'slow')
```

Однако работать это будет только в том случае, если содержимое `iframe` находится на одном и том же домене, что и ваш сайт. Такова политика безопасности.